# dijit.byId set readOnly is not working in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, dojo

I have a HTML form where I need to set a field as non-editable. As setting it as "disabled" element carries NULL value to backend, i am opting for "readonly".

I have sent the field readonly as -

```
dijit.byId("C_id").set('readOnly',true);
```

and C_id is declared as

```
<tr>
   <td>c id</td>
   <td><input id="C_id" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" name="CID" required="true" trim = "true"/>
   </td>
</tr>
```

This is working fine with Firefox (any vesion) but with IE9 it is giving me a weird behavior. In IE 9, the field is showing readonly but when I select the field and press "backspace" the webpage goes back to the previous page.

Can you please let me know what mistake I have made? Is there any known issue with IE 9 related to dijit?

Thanks

Dipankaj

Comment: When a field is not selected it is normal browser behavior for the backspace to go to previous page in history. Chrome does the same thing.

Comment: thanks tik ... but then why Firefox is not behaving the same way??

Comment: Because apparently Firefox handles backspace differently. This is not a HTML issue but an issue with how browsers handle the keystroke backspace.